# Caminhos duplicados na variável de ambiente $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

Tenho percebido que os caminhos que eu adiciono ao `$PATH` no meu `.bashrc` aparecem duplicados quando abro sessão em `tmux` (terminal multiplexer):

```
export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Devel/bin
```

Se eu imprimir `$PATH` numa sessão de `tmux` ele aparece da seguinte forma:

```
/home/alejandro/miniconda3/bin:/home/alejandro/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/alejandro/Devel/bin:/home/alejandro/Devel/bin
```

Fora de `tmux` ele aparece normal:

```
/home/alejandro/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/alejandro/Devel/bin
```

Eu suspeito que tem a ver com a primeira linha do meu `.bash_profile`:

```
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Se eu comentar essa linha (que não entendo muito bem qual a função dela), o `$PATH` aparece correto dentro e fora da sessão de `tmux`, só que eu perco a customização do prompt do script `bash-git-prompt` dentro da sessão do `tmux`. Aparentemente `tmux` acessa o script do `bash-git-prompt` por meio de `.bash_profile`.

Por enquanto a solução que achei foi:

- comentar a primeira linha do `bash_profile`;
- copiar as linhas do `.bashrc` sobre o `bash-git-prompt` script dentro do `.bash_profile` (agora essas linhas estão nos dois arquivos).

Com isso, o `$PATH` aparece corretamente dentro e fora da sessão do `tmux` e o mesma coisa com o prompt.

A minha dúvida é se está certo ou se existe uma outra forma mais correta de se fazer.

Editado:

[.bash_profile](https://github.com/aledruetta/dotfiles/blob/master/bash_profile)

[.bashrc](https://github.com/aledruetta/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc)

Comment: A linha que você disse que não sabia o que faz interpreta o arquivo .bashrc, caso ele exista no diretório home do usuário atual. Você fez esses `export`s em mais de um lugar? Ou interpreta .bashrc mais de uma vez? Se não, considere postar os arquivos .bashrc e .bash_profile junto com a sua pergunta.

Comment: @Genos, adicionei os arquivos como solicitado.